# mootools errors in Joomla

Tags: javascript, joomla, mootools

I'm having a problem.. the site is working correctly in safari, chrome and firefox (mac and win) but in Internet explorer I get an error related with mootools: Line: 59 Character: 102.

The site URL is: http://example.com (I've removed the url for security reasons)

I've noticed that mootools is being loaded two times, maybe another component is calling it again, how can I remove this call?? or how can I locate witch component is making this call??

Another thing is the gmaps doesn't work (only in IE)(it worked before)
This map is generated by a component named iproperty, I've asked in the support forums but no responses.

This is very frustrating because I didn't make the site and I don't know what was installed wrong.

Any advice or directions will be very appreciated.

Thank you guys,
Luis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. finally solved, the problem was the initial coordinates of google maps were incorrect and Internet explorer stops working. Strange thing.

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you search through your web site's source code to identify where MooTools is embedded. It could probably be any plugin.

As for Google Maps not working in IE, I'm pretty sure that is down to the MooTools problem as well.

Comment: yes.. mootools is being loaded two times by `<jdoc:include type="head" />` .. but I don't know how to remove one of these calls.. I mean, to add a script you use `$document->addScript( ‘/media/system/js/sample.js’ );` ... and how do you remove a script??

Comment: @Luis I don't know whether that's possible. You may be better off finding the second `addScript` and removing it.

Answer (score 1):

I hope that  is not used twice (or am I... this makes this the solution for the problem...)
If this is the case, let me know and I'll guide you through it.

Otherwise,
It is not possible to remove a script (without changing the JDocument class), as there is no method for removing scripts and the access to the _scripts array, where scripts are stored, is private.

This is not the proper solution, either.
As @Pekka pointed out, try to find the cause for the extra addition of the script.
It is probable that either the template or one of the plugins is to blame.
Do you have a local copy of the site? You can start off by disabling some of the plugins and changing the template to see which is the cause.
Then, pinpoint the insubordinate piece of code. If you have a local copy of the files, you can search for the exact point of inclusion and figure out what exactly is going on. It is highly strange for anything to include the mootools core files.